# nginx server config issue: page not found 404 if not using parent folder in root param

Tags: php, nginx, php-7, prestashop-1.7

I have all source code for prestashop site in **/var/www/xyz** folder but when accessing it I am getting 404 page not found error at **www.xyz.com** with root param is /var/www/xyz.

However when changing root param to parent folder i.e **/var/www/** I can access the website at **www.xyz.com/xyz.**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/xyz;
        index index.php;
        server_name xyz.com www.xyz.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

Can anyone please help how to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Your nginx config seems fine to me at first glance. Have you [configured presta](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Setting+a+shop%27s+URL) properly ?

Comment: Hey , Prestashop working fine if I am changing root to  parent folder. i.e. / var/www/ but getting accessible at xyz.com/xyz

Comment: Check the docs I linked in previous comment, you have to 'declare' it in presta if you want to change your context root directory.

Comment: You are correct. I followed document and set base uri to / to get it done. Thank You so much :)